# PHP spits out the course/location/time of event, combine results to create item store on page with session and create cart item to send to paypal?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, session-variables, shopping-cart

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $eventSelect = $_POST['eventSelect'];
    $eventLocation = $_POST['eventLocation'];
    $eventDate = $_POST['eventDate'];

    echo "Event Name:";echo $eventName;

    echo "<br /><br />Event Location:";echo $eventLocation;

    echo "<br /><br />From :"; echo $eventDate;
}
```

When a user goes to the site they are presented with a drop down that lists the Event, and updates based on selection.  Is there a way I can give the result of this an item number that I can than have enter a simple php cart through a session_start and then be directed to paypal using a checkout button?  Or should I add an item number to each item in the database? Since a user has to result in one of those results anyway? If I was to do that how would one call that last field after the query? Is that possible?

Sorry if this is redundant I'm not used to working with shopping carts.

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence. Do not forget to breathe when you speak.

Comment: yeah sorry.  Basically a user goes through the drop downs which are dynamically updated -> A button shows up saying register. I have it now so it just shows the selected items as an echo.  Is there a way that I can take those results and give them an item number or something along the lines of that. Than add it to a simple shopping cart? Allowing them to either register for another event and or just go to checkout through paypal.  Also, how complex would it be to construct a simple cart like that? I wouldn't have to create or embed a CMS system would I?

Comment: I think you are confusing 'then' and 'than', that's why did not understand (and I'm french, which does not help either). I think what you mean to do is transfer the cart from anonymous user to logged in user? If you're looking for a small cart, have a look to prestashop, if you're looking for something with more features, try magento. They usually store the cart in the session I think.

Comment: Thanks I've looked at prestacart and just glanced over Magento and even that was too heavy, I'm not trying to have a user system at all I'm actually trying to avoid that.  I"m trying to allow them to hold the first selection they make through the drop downs in a session/cart so they have the option to either go to paypal or add another course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically this is handled by the user of an auto_increment column in your database. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(50) not null,
    `location` varchar(100) not null,
    `date` datetime not null,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO events (name, location, date) VALUES('Foo', 'Bar', '2010-07-10 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO events (name, location, date) VALUES('Baz', 'Foo', '2010-11-10 00:00:00');

SELECT * FROM events;
+----+------+----------+---------------------+
| id | name | location | date                |
+----+------+----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Foo  | Bar      | 2010-07-10 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Baz  | Foo      | 2010-11-10 00:00:00 |
+----+------+----------+---------------------+
```

You can see that the database automatically assigned the value for `id`. It will never give the same value to different events. This becomes a unique "event id" that you can save in a session.